# Calculating percentage loaded of mp4 with Soundmanager 2

Tags: javascript, html, mp4, soundmanager2

I'm trying to calculate the percentage loaded of an mp4 file with Soundmanager2, using HTML5. In both of the following examples the code is called each time the *whileloading* event fires on the loading *SMSound* object:

```
// This is the method suggested in the Soundmanager2 documentation
// http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-buffered

var percentageLoaded, i, durationLoaded = 0;
for (i = 0; i < this.buffered.length; i++) {
  durationLoaded += (this.buffered[i].end - this.buffered[i].start);
}
percentageLoaded = durationLoaded / this.duration * 100;
```

This example results in *percentageLoaded* having a value of *NaN*, because *duration* remains at *0* throughout loading. I have also tried *durationEstimate* in the place of *duration*, which also remains set to *0*. The response header contains the correct *Content-Type* value (*audio/mp4*) and *Content-Length* value, however the duration seems to be ignored by Soundmanager2 in this case.

```
var percentageLoaded = audio.bytesLoaded / audio.bytesTotal * 100;
```

This example results in *percentageLoaded* having a value of *0*, because *bytesTotal* remains at *1* and *bytesLoaded* remains at *0* until the audio is completely loaded. Again, the *Content-Range* value in the header correctly reports the number of bytes, but the value is ignored by Soundmanager2.

Is there a method which I haven't yet tried which could correctly report the percentage, or a factor I've overlooked which would cause this problem? Is this simply a limitation of Soundmanager2 while loading mp4s?

Edit 1:
All values are correct after the onload event fires though, and the sound plays with no problems.

Edit 2:
Here's an example on CodePen of what happens:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EiIch

Comment: Have a look at the example posted in the Soundmanager docs about buffering. That would probably be an easier solution that trying to calc bytes loaded http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-buffered

Comment: This is the method I'm currently using and I'm having the issues I described in my original question. The bytesLoaded/bytesTotal example was another method I tried.

Comment: Can you post your code in a JSFiddle or Codepen, so we can see it live?

Comment: I've added a CodePen example at the end of my question.